# python logging formatter order and formating record

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a custom formatter for my Python console log.

Can someone help me how the whole thing could look nicer and maybe in a for loop?

I get a long log in the class with a lot of keys and values that I don't need for the console. I want to filter and sort 4 or if available 5 values out of the object.

This is my code:

```
class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def_keys = ['asctime', 'name', 'levelname', 'msg']
    def_keys_id = ['asctime', 'name', 'levelname', 'ID', 'msg']

    def format(self, record):
        extra = {k: v for k, v in record.__dict__.items()
                 if k in self.def_keys_id}
        extra = collections.OrderedDict(extra)
        if len(extra) > 4:
            for k in self.def_keys_id:
                extra.move_to_end(k)
            b = list(extra.values())
            c = b[0]+" - "+b[1]+" - "+b[2]+" - "+b[3]+" - "+b[4]
        else:
            for k in self.def_keys:
                extra.move_to_end(k)
            b = list(extra.values())
            c = b[0]+" - "+b[1]+" - "+b[2]+" - "+b[3]
        return str(c)
```

Sorted and formatted then come back that:

```
Wed Jan  5 11:10:00 2022 - main_logger - INFO - 12345 - run main
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why do you need a custom formatter for this? Looks to me you just want to pass a specific format? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles

Comment: I need the custom formatter for the console logger, as my other main logger does need the information separately not in a string or in the message. But with the console logger it should be all in one string, as above.